# What's wrong with the indentation? Python, Rock Paper Scissors Game

Tags: python, indentation

These are the instructions: This program should be written using a menu driven interface. It should contain at least 6 functions, as follows (you can have more if you think you need others). You should choose descriptive function names to properly describe their function (follow the convention for properly naming functions). Just to be clear, you should NOT have functions called function1, function2, etc. Replace the names below with your own function names in your code.

When I run it, I get an error code saying "expected an indented block" for the line `if comp(==1 and user ==3)`.

Please let me know what's wrong, thanks!

```
#import random module
import random
#main function
def main():
    #program message
    print("Rock, Paper, Scissors Game")
    #initializing variables that would hold choices of user and computer
    comp = 1
    user = 1

while comp == user:
    print("Enter your choice in range from 1 to 3")
    #prompt user to enter choice
    user = int(input("Your choice: "))
    #randomly assign choice to computer
    comp = random.randint(1,3)
    #display choice of computer
    print("Computer Choice : ",comp)
    #display game drawn message, when same choices

if (comp == user):
    print("Game Drawn. Select again")
    #calling function to decide winner
    winner (comp, user)
    #winner function
    def winner(comp, user):
    #rock and scissor choice

if(comp == 1 and user ==3):
    print("Computer win")
print("The rock smashes scissor")
    elif(comp == 3 and user ==1):
        print("User win")
        print("The rock smashes scissor")
    else:
    #paper and rock choice

if(comp == 1 and user == 2):
    print("User win")
    print("The paper wraps rock")
        elif (comp == 2 and user ==1):
            print("Computer win")
            print("Scissors cut paper")
        elif (comp == 2 and user == 3):
            print("User win")
            print("Scissors cut paper")
        else:
            print("Invalid selection")
            #calling main function

main()
```

Comment: The line right before it is a `def`, which expects an indented block, and you don't have one.

Comment: There are more indentation problems here than I could enumerate.

Comment: @FredLarson - Looking at it more thoroughly, you are absolutely right. It's all kinds of messed up.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the answer from Nathaniel Ford, your if-elif-else indendation is wrong at some places as well.

```
if (condition):
    print "hi"
elif (condition):
    print "hi again"
else:
    print "hi again vol3"
```

This is the correct way to indendent if-elif-else conditions.

Comment: `if` structures (and other things that require varied indentation levels, like loops) don't have their own scope.

Comment: You are correct. I will edit my post to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the previous code line:

```
def winner(comp, user):
```

`def` is defining a function, and expects that function to have a body. Because you back the indentation out to the top level, the `def` body has nothing (not even a `pass`), and thus won't compile.

But note that isn't your only indentation problem. The definition of `main` prints one line `print("Rock, Paper, Scissors Game")`, and then sets some variables and... quits. Because the indentation of `while comp == user:` backs out a level, it doesn't exist inside the `main` definition. This a problem with pretty much every new block of your code. You should read up how [Python structures code with indentation](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php).